# Show/Hide html ul with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to show hidden nested lists when the previous list element is clicked. To do this I want to modify what classes the html element has. I haven't used JavaScript/jQuery before so I am a bit confused as to how to attempt this.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('li').click(function () {
    if ($(this).next('ul').hasClass("hidden")) {
        $(this).next('ul').removeClass("hidden");
        $(this).next('ul').addClass("visible");
    } else if ($(this).next('ul').hasClass("visible")) {
        $(this).next('ul').removeClass("visble");
        $(this).next('ul').addClass("hidden");
    }
});
</script>

<ul class="year">
    <li>2013</li>
    <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Nov</li>
        <ul class="hidden">
            <li>25</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your markup is incorrect. You cannot have `ul` as direct children of `ul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--Invalid HTML structure fixed, ul should have li elements as its children-->
<ul class="year">
    <li>2013
        <ul class="hidden">
            <li>Nov
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li>25</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The main problem is you are not using [dom ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function () {
    $('li').click(function (e) {
        //stop propagation else parent li elements click handlers will get triggered
        e.stopPropagation();
        //use toggleClasss
        $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('hidden visible')
    });
})
```

then you can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to switch the classes

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("id").toggle();
```

That should do it.